# Unable to assign overflow visible with FlashList?

Tags: reactjs, native, flatlist

I know that the above is possible via FlatList and ScrollView etc. however, the Shopify FlashList component seems to be unable to assign the `overflow : visible` property to the container.

Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds? I'm contemplating adding a patch.

Comment: That's someone who misspelled FlatList. I'm referring to FlashList, the Shopify one

Comment: Ya got it referred above mistakenly instead of below one https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list/issues/723